# Exclude rows if LEFT JOIN table record count is more than one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, left-join

Two tables:

Table1  `fax_history`

```
fax_key
1001
1002
```

Table2 > `fax_history_status`

```
fax_key     Status
1001        NEW
1001        SUCCESS
1002        NEW
```

Now I need to write a `join query` which will return only `fax_key=1002` record because `fax_key=1001` has MORE THAN ONE record in `fax_history_status` table.

So the query result should be:

```
fax_key     status
1002        NEW
```

Comment: Can you frame the sample data as table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could filter the rows using `having`

```
select a.fax_key 
from  fax_history a
inner  join  fax_history_status  b on  a.fax_key  = b.fax_key 
 group by a.fax_key
 having count(*) =1
```

for status you could use a (fake) aggregation function eg:

```
select a.fax_key , min(b.status)
from  fax_history a
inner  join  fax_history_status  b on  a.fax_key  = b.fax_key 
 group by a.fax_key
 having count(*) =1
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge your query returns as expected but when I tried to add b.status in select and group by it's giving all 3 records. Is there any twist to get fax_key and status both?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the basic query like that

```
SELECT * FROM fax 

INNER JOIN faxstatus ON fax.faxkey=faxstatus.faxkey AND faxstatus.faxkey IN

(

SELECT faxkey  FROM faxstatus

GROUP BY faxkey

HAVING COUNT(faxkey)=1


)
```